# RealmSwift obtain each T object

Tags: ios, realm, rxdatasources

I have list of objects `T` and I want to calculate their sum (`T` objects)

```
var objects: Observable<List<T>>
```

`T` object has a method which return `Int` value.
The main idea to get each object and prepare array of values (`flatMap` function). The next step will be `reduce` func with `Int` values.

```
let sum = values.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

Q: How to get each `T` object?

Comment: Use `realm.objects(T.self)` to get all objects of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the solution below which is trying to demonstrate what you are trying to do, you might need a protocol for type T that has int property like the example below. You can try it with playground.

```
protocol Countable {

    var value: Int { get }
    init(value: Int)
}


class User: Countable {

    var value: Int = 0

    required convenience init(value: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.value = value
    }
}


class UserGroup<T: Countable> {

    func calculateTotal() {
        let users: [T] = [T(value: 2), T(value: 21)]
        let total = users.flatMap { ($0 as Countable).value }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        print("total", total)
    }
}

let userGroup = UserGroup<User>()
userGroup.calculateTotal()
```